# How to Create dynamic tbody onclick of button using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dynamic

I have this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Try to get tbody first with jquery children. works faster!
    var tbody = $('#myTable').children('tbody');

    //Then if no tbody just select your table 
    var table = tbody.length ? tbody : $('#myTable');


    $('button').click(function() {
        //Add row
        table.append('<tr>\n\
        <td><input name="product_name[]" type="text"/></td>\n\
        <td><input name="qty[]" type="text"/></td>\n\
        <td><input name="price[]" type="text"/></td>\n\
        </tr>');
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="row_no" type="text" placeholder="Type Your Number of row"  />
<button>Add row</button>
<table id="myTable">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th class="column-title">Product name</th>
         <th class="column-title">Quantity</th>
         <th class="column-title">Price</th>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

When I click on the button *Add row*, it appends a row to the table.

But now, I have a textbox in the HTML. I want to append the table to generate rows based on the value of:

```
<input name="row_no" type="text" placeholder="Type Your Number of row"  />
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Try to get tbody first with jquery children. works faster!
    var tbody = $('#myTable').children('tbody');

    //Then if no tbody just select your table 
    var table = tbody.length ? tbody : $('#myTable');

    $('[name=row_no]').text();

    $('button').click(function() {

        var rows = $('[name=row_no]').val();

        // If rows are at maximum 10,
        if (!(rows > 10)) {
            // then add rows
            for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                table.append('<tr>\n\
      <td><input name="product_name[]" type="text"/></td>\n\
      <td><input name="qty[]" type="text"/></td>\n\
      <td><input name="price[]" type="text"/></td>\n\
      </tr>');
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Error: Too many rows!\n" +
                  "Maximum allowed: 10\n" +
                  "- Inserted: " + rows);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
   <input name="row_no" type="number" placeholder="Type Your Number of row"  />
   <button>Add row</button>
   <table id="myTable">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th class="column-title">Product name</th>
            <th class="column-title">Quantity</th>
            <th class="column-title">Price</th>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</body>
```

### **What changed?**

- You needed to get the value inserted in the textfield, this can be achieved using, in this case: `$('[name=row_no]').val();`, so I valorised it as `rows` variable and then the only thing to add was a cycle that creates as many rows as the user inserts.
- I also changed
  `<input name="row_no" type="text" placeholder="Type Your Number of row"  />`
  to `<input name="row_no" type="number" placeholder="Type Your Number of row"  />`.
   This little change allows the user to insert only integers and this is a nice solution to avoid time-loss because of writing a new function to validate values inserted.

### **Edit:**

- Added a control on about how many rows the user can insert with `if (!(rows > 10))` condition (if you need more or less rows, the only thing to edit is the number)